# How can i add a div using semantic ui in another?

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

i have this function

```
createSection = () => {   
     let div = document.createElement("div")
     div.innerHTML =
                    `<section>
                        <Grid centered>
                            <Item.Header  style={{'paddingBottom': '20px', color: 'red'}} as='h1'>{this.state.contents.inputTitle}</Item.Header>
                        </Grid>
                        <Item.Description style={{'maxWidth': '100%'}}>
                            {this.state.contents.inputContent}
                        </Item.Description>
                        <Item.Extra></Item.Extra>
                    </section`             
     document.getElementById("teste").appendChild(div)
}
```

and i want to add a section in the div

```
<div onClick={this.createSection} id='teste' style={{'backgroundColor':'#178776', 'boxShadow':'inset 0 3px 27px 19px rgba(15,56,94,.6)', 'borderRadius': '30px', padding: '30px'}}>    
</div>
```

But what appear in div is: `{this.state.contents.inputTitle}` `{this.state.contents.inputContent}`
What i have to do for this works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Deborah Luperini, you should not create components in such way in React because it does not vanilla JS, you have to either use JSX, i made [working example](https://codepen.io/KoldunMax/pen/BMrNPv)

or last decision and not the best it a using `React.createElement` where you need set your parent element, properties and children, i found an example with unordered list, may be it helps you, but **i am not recommend** use it:

```
React.createElement("ul", {"className": "ingredients"},
   React.createElement("li", null, "1 lb Salmon"),
   React.createElement("li", null, "1 cup Pine Nuts"),
   React.createElement("li", null, "2 cups Butter Lettuce"),
   React.createElement("li", null, "1 Yellow Squash"),
   React.createElement("li", null, "1/2 cup Olive Oil"),
   React.createElement("li", null, "3 cloves of Garlic")
);
```

hope it'll help you, good regards

Comment: is React Component, but I really need to do the way I put it in the example, as I need to add a div inside the test div every time the button is clicked

Comment: What is the button ? I do not see here any buttons

If you need add a div inside the test div every time when the button is clicked you have to add event 'click' on this button, for instance:

`<button onClick={this.createSection} >Add a div inside test div</button>`

and delete 'click' event from the test div

Comment: you are don't understand... i need to use `let div = document.createElement("div")
     div.(someone event) = ...` i have a button to start this event, but in this exemple i put it in div... i want to `<div id='teste'><div>click 1</div><div>click 2</div>...</div>`

Comment: in such way you need use an array, i made example, see above

Comment: thaks for your help dude! you really help me :)